# Any known Twitter REST and Stream API NodeJS modules that support running behind a proxy?

Tags: node.js, twitter

I  have tried a few of the known modules (twitter, tuiter) and they seem not to support cases in which the app is ran behind a proxy. Are there any modules that do support that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this by running the node binary through proxychains. There are many forks of proxychains floating around, this one worked for me:

https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng